# Mongoose : Error referencing sub schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, models, mongoose-schema

My user model

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    username: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    initials: String,
    password: String,
    age: Number,
    dateJoined: Date,
    contactNo: String,
    email: String,
    about: String,

    groupId: Number,
    adminMode: Boolean,
    simpulPoints: Number,
})

//Define model for user
const User = {
    UserModel: mongoose.model("user", UserSchema),

}


module.exports = {
    UserSchema : UserSchema,
    User : User
}
```

My Events Model

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = require("../models/user").UserSchema


var EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema();
EventSchema.add({
    id: String,
    title: String,
    description: String,
    organizerId: String, //Simpul admin user responsible for event
    startDate: Date, //MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS:sssZ
    endDate: Date,
    group: String,
    locaction: String,
    googleMapsLink: String,
    hasPassed: Boolean,
    attendees: Number,

    registeredUsers: [UserSchema],

    groupId: Number,
    adminMode: Boolean,
    simpulAward: Number,
});

//Define model for evnt
var Event = {

    EventModel : mongoose.model("event", EventSchema),

}

module.exports = {
    Event : Event,
    EventSchema : EventSchema
}
```

I'm getting the infamous "throw new TypeError('Invalid value for schema Array path" error with the 'registeredUsers' field. I've followed multiple posts with the same problem and can't seem to find where I am going wrong. According to my knowledge, I've exported the schemas appropriately.  Any help/tips welcome

Comment: The error suggests that `UserSchema` is `null` or `undefined`, but from what you're showing, I don't see how. In fact, I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: @robertklep Yes, it's strange. If I include the UserSchema in the same file,  the definition works no problem, Thus something must be going wrong in the exporting...

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(UserSchema)` right before creating `EventSchema`? Or even right after importing it.

Comment: I have done so and get `undefined` as result. I've also just tried exporting a simple literal from the same file and also get `undefined`

Comment: In that case, I would suspect the `models/user.js` file. Provided it's the correct file, it may be doing something strange with `module.exports` or `exports`.

Comment: I ended up moving the Schema declarations out into a separate file and it seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the Schema declarations out into a separate file and it seemed to do the trick. Suspect it must have been some file rights issue VSCode had with the users.js file